# "Глупый, как пробка"

Tags: фразеология

Почитала очень интересные ответы на вопрос о дубе и лопухе. Как альтернатива "дубу" там приводится выражение "тупой, как пробка" или "глупый, как пробка". Странное сравнение — чем народу пробка не угодила?))))

Comment: А запятая нужна? Викисловарь говорит, что "тупой как пробка" - это устойчивое словосочетание и пишется без запятой.

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Михельсона  говорится, что это часть пословицы "Глуп, как пробка, куда ни ткнёшь, там и торчит"
http://onlineslovari.com/bolshoy_tolkovo_frazeologicheskiy_slovar_mihelsona/page/glup_kak_probka.1938

Answer (score 1):

Насчет "куда воткнешь" - не спорю, эта версия дается везде как основная или даже единственная. 
Смущает, однако, при чем тут глупость, даже в полном варианте.

Просто для полноты картины замечу, что исходно слово "пробка" пришло из немецкого, и означало сначала не вынимаемую затычку для сосуда с жидкостью, но кору дуба, из которой такие затычки делались. А это уже отдельная версия. Кора такая еще "глупее" самой дубовой древесины - крошится, трескается, вечно в дефектах... Но приходится пользоваться ради главного качества - упругости.

ЗЫ Будет техническая возможность - идею разовью.

Comment: Ну, где-так. Еще есть не менее обидное - дубина, или вообще дуб. Вот только от немецкого пробка, вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

Когда человеку объясняют долго суть дела или вопроса и это обращается в бесполезное занятие то применяют пословицу, потому что у пробки (будучи первоначально в форме усеченного конуса) из-за своей формы и назначения тоже имеется предел в применении.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на вопрос, почему "тупой как пробка - куда воткнешь, там и торчит". Видимо, в старину особо глупыми считали не столько малограмотных и малообразованных, сколько подверженных чужому мнению и манипуляциям. То есть, куда "воткнешь" человека (какую мысль внушишь), там он и будет находиться (примет чужое мнение и будет так же думать, не подвергая его сомнению).

Comment: Вопрос от 2013 года уже имеет ответы того же времени схожие с этим. Свежий текст должен ли нести новое содержание?

Answer (score 0):

Глуп как пробка.
А вот моя версия такая: пробка очень легкая, легче воды, и поэтому всегда на поверхности плавает, то есть всегда глупость вылезает наружу. Думаю, где-то схоже с "дерьмо не тонет": и там, и здесь все на поверхности.